# If $X = U\Sigma V^T$ and $\|Y\|=1$, why does $Y = UV^T$ maximize $\langle X,Y\rangle$?

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, duality-theorems, svd

Let

1. Let $\|M\| := \sigma_{max}(M)$, i.e. the spectral norm of $M$.
2. $\langle X,Y \rangle = \text{Trace}(X^TY)$. Inner product of two matrices.

How to prove the title:

> If $X = U\Sigma V^T$ and $\|Y\|=1$, why $Y = UV^T$ maximizes $\langle X,Y\rangle$

As a consequence:

1. We know since $Y=UIV^T$, so $\sigma_{max}(Y) = 1$.
2. Trace$(X^TY) = $trace$(\Sigma)$ = $\|X\|_*$, which is the nuclear norm.

The above is the key to prove that spectral norm and nuclear norm are dual.

(Also if you are interested in this proof, "[Show that the dual norm of the spectral norm is the nuclear norm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1158798/show-that-the-dual-norm-of-spectral-norm-is-nuclear-norm)" is a good reference.)

---

Thank  @angryavian.  The proof is the following:

[image]

> I met another problem:  how to show the **last two** equalities?

Comment: I think [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1142540/proof-that-nuclear-norm-is-convex/1145246#1145246) (which was linked in the comments of your link) answers this question. His $Q$ is your $Y$, and his $A$ is your $X$.

Comment: It is a version of Procrustes' (or procrustean) Problem.

Comment: Is $\mathrm X$ given?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo $X$ is given or not is not important. But yes $X$ is given since we know its SVD.

Comment: @sleevechen You may want to take a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1963711/339790